# How to pass current view controller to the function as parameter in swift

Tags: swift

I want to pass current view controller as a parameter so that I could reuse the functions of it I am defining "commonFunction(currentController:UIViewController)" in my CommonUtils class but it's throwing an error

```
static func commonFunction(currentController:UIViewController, dictionary: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
  currentController.getDownloadURL(email: String.getString(currentController.userDetails[JsonKeys.Kemail]),orgId: String.getString(currentController.userDetails[JsonKeys.KorganizationId]), fileId: Int.getInt(dictionary[JsonKeys.KtypeId]))
}
```

error details:

1. Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'getDownloadURL'
2. Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'userDetails'

Comment: Can you paste us the error?

Comment: Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'getDownloadURL'
Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'userDetails'

Comment: Well its pretty straightforward, you take a UIViewController as a parameter but there is no such vars in a UIViewController class. You should pass your subclass type instead of `UIViewController` ( e.g. `MyCustomViewController`)

Comment: but the same code is used in many controllrs

Comment: so I would I make it dynamic

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is unclear actually. Why a UIViewController would have these values? What is the purpose of those values, why do you need to gather them, in what particular situation do you need those values. Please be more specific so we can understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

This `currentController:UIViewController` is a generic vc it has no methods/properties you called `getDownloadURL/userDetails`  you need to pass the actual vc instance that has those methods/properties `currentController:MyViewController`

or create a superClass vc that all instances are childs of it and insert those methods/properties inside it